# Python, can xpath locate a picture based on the width of the photo then click that picture?

Tags: python

I am teaching myself how to use xpath on python and a specific website that I am practicing on uses a different unique title  in the 
`<img alt="title"> </img>` for each picture that I need to document, removing my ability to reuse the code for different photos. However, I noticed that all the photos on this website uses the width = "110" function. Would it be possible to use xpath to search the webpage to find the first photo that contains width="110" and clicks that photo? The photo's are also always located within a list html tag. Or as a last resort, in lieu of that solution, search the page for all images and click on the third image it finds on the page?

```
Here is the actual image code:
<li> <img alt="cblack365" title="cblack365" width="110" src="https://pic1.com/482/482312/0004fe6f-a9b6-6010-5df5-698454429ede_110.jpg?token=1573171200_a06462a1993482c0f9399a45ef726a416c15a577a18da7a125e120a89b6e9d0d">  </li

Code I have tried; 
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class='width="110"']').click
```

Answer (score 0):

`width` and `class` are separate attributes. Try

```
img[@width=110]
```

Comment: linkElem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*img[@width=110]"]')
                                                                                                                linkElem.click()

Comment: You can't have both `*` and `img`. Use `'//img[@width=110]'`